# How to extract method from its class in order to reused it in many places and keep encapsulation?

Tags: c#, oop, refactoring

I'm writing ATM software in order to train object-oriented programming and I have got Pin class with a VerifyPin method.

```
    class Pin
{
    private int _pin;

    public void ChangePin (int newPin)
    {
        if (newPin.ToString().Length != 4)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("PIN must be exactly 4 digits long");
        }

        _pin = newPin;
    }

    public bool VerifyPin (int pin)
    {
        return (_pin == pin);
    }


}
```

I'm trying to call this method inside other classes in order to verify PIN which is stored inside Card, as well as Account.

So far I came up with an idea to do something like this, but I'm sure there is a better way

```
    class Card
{
    private Pin _pin;

    public Card(Pin pin)
    {
        this._pin = pin;   

    public bool VerifyPin (int pin)
    {
        return this._pin.VerifyPin(pin);
    }
}
```

Any sources to learn more about subject will be welcomed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the pin should be encapsulated in an Account, but not a Card.  A card would be associated with an account.  So to verify a pin when given a card you would call the following code:

```
bool verified = myCard.Account.VerifyPin(pin);
```

(A static method doesn't work because it can't access the field `_pin`).

Comment: But is it a good practise to call method Account.VerifyPin(pin) just to transfer parameter to this._pin.VerifyPin(pin)? Or maybe making Pin a public get only property and using it as Account.Pin.VerifyPin(pin) would be a better way.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about the Law of Demeter. So there should be a myCard.VerifyAccountPin(pin).  I'm too lazy to do that! http://c2.com/cgi/wiki/LawOfDemeter?LawOfDemeter

Answer (score 2):

This method can be made static. This way it could be accessed and used from any class in the same project,
But seems what you would like to create a pin object and then call that object method : VerifyPin that will take the pin you want to validate as parameter

Comment: I fought about making it static, but in my opinion it broke encapsulation because I need to pass pin stored in account class as parameter. And what I want to do is to pass something to function inside my class and compare it there. If my way of thinking is wrong I'm open to change it.

Comment: Option 1: All classes that contains pin that needs to be validated can take in their ctor another class parameter called PinValidator. This PinValidator will have the pin data member and the validate function,

Comment: Option 2 is to make the Validate method in PinValidator static and than you won't need a PinValidator in every ctor, only call PinValidator.ValidatePin(pinNumber)

Comment: Is it a good practise to make pin a public get only property, and call Card object.Pin.Varifypin(pinToVerify)?

Comment: Seems like a mess to have a verifyPin inside the Pin class that takes another pin

Comment: My idea it to pass user input there and validate it with pin stored in card, as well as in account object

Answer (score 0):

If you make the VerifyPin method static you may call it without creating an instance of the Pin class.

```
public static bool VerifyPin(int pin){}

Pin.VerifyPin(pin);
```